# Error while installing R packages

Tags: r, ubuntu-12.04

While trying to install the 'Rook' package in R i'm getting the following error:

```
** package ‘Rook’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
sh: 1: -f: not found
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Rook’
* removing ‘/usr/lib/R/site-library/Rook’

The downloaded packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpPW6kC2/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("Rook", repos = "http://cran.r-project.org") :
  installation of package ‘Rook’ had non-zero exit status
```

I used both the install.packages() function and the terminal to install the package, but received the same message. Any ideas?

OS: Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: you might want to try to download Rstudio and use that package manager, it helps to automatically download dependencies (I can't make up that this is the problem but it might be).

Comment: @VincentWarmerdam you mean the same way as `install.packages( ..., dependencies=TRUE )`?

Comment: this is what it eventually does yes, Rstudio gives you a little more insight in the versions of the dependencies installed as well (it's more a visual help as well). dependencies=TRUE does not help? I get the response that 'brew' is needed as well and Rstudio installs this.

Comment: @VincentWarmerdam tried installing using RStudio. Same error.

Comment: Can you download the tar.gz and install locally? [Direct link to download file](http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Rook_1.0-9.tar.gz). Probably won't change anything. What version of R are you on?

Comment: Works for me on Ubuntu 12.04. Looks like your missing some dependencies for r-base-core, please check (for example gcc or something).

Comment: @MadScone same error with local install. The R version I'm using is 2.14.1